How can I increase the TPS of Active Report js In Node js
Here is the problem,
I am using Active Report Js to generate reports in multiple formats. I have created a project where we can generate PDF,HTML and CSV. Before that we have to design the report and which will be in the form of rdlx-json.
https://github.com/GrapeCity/activereportsjs-samples/blob/main/arjs-server-mode/index.js
You can refer to the above GitHub project. Instead of playwright, we are using Puppeteer library as it has no vulnerabilities.
Can anyone of you guys help me increase the performance of the project.
Here is the below code which generates report using puppeteer library
Reports are getting generated but if we try to do load test then it is going to through "Invalid Raw JSON" because of timeout because of puppeteer library.
{ TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (/project/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NavigatorWatcher.js:74:21)
    at <anonymous> name: 'TimeoutError' 
}

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const _ = require('lodash');
const logger = require('../helpers/logger')('PDF SERVICE');
const config = require('../../configs/environment');
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
const axios = require('axios');
const { createJsonFile } = require('../controller/template');
const minioService = require('./minioService');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let postMessageToMaster = (data) => {
  parentPort.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data))
}

let reportGenerate = async (data) => {
  //console.log(data)
  try {
    logger.info("reportGenerate init")
    let fileName = `${data.templateName}.rdlx-json`
    let attachmentType = '';
    var extentionType, settings = {};
    if (data.attachmentType === "HTML") {
      attachmentType += "HTML";
      extentionType = "html";
      settings = {
        "info": {
          "autoPrint": true,
          "embedImages": "embed",
          "multiPage": false,
          "outputType": "auto",
          "title": fileName
        }
      }
    }
    if (data.attachmentType === "XLSX") {
      attachmentType += "XLSX";
      extentionType = "xlsx";
      settings = {
        "info": {
          "creator": data.appUser
        }
      }
    }
    if (data.attachmentType === "PDF") {
      attachmentType += "PDF";
      extentionType = "pdf";
      settings = {
        "info": {
          "title": fileName,
          "author": data.appUser
        },
        "security": {
          "userPassword": data.userPassword,
          "ownerPassword": data.ownerPassword
        }

      }
    }
    if (data.attachmentType === "CSV") {
      attachmentType += "CSV";
      extentionType = "csv";
      settings = {
        "colSeparator": ",",
        "outputType": "plain",
        "quotationSymbol": '"',
        "rowSeparator": "\n",
        "tableSeparator": "",
      }
    }

    logger.info(fileName, " generate as ", attachmentType)
    const url = `http://localhost:9001/dap-reports/index.html`;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: "new",
      args: [
        "--font-render-hinting=none",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--incognito",
        "--remote-debugging-port=0",
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--allow-running-insecure-content"
      ]
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    //console.log("context", context)

    const reportString = await page.evaluate(async ({ reportData }) => {
      try {
        await GC.ActiveReports.Core.FontStore.registerFonts("fontsConfig.json");
        var onProgressCallback = (pageCount) => {
          console.log(pageCount, "Pages are ready to export as ", reportData.attachmentType);
        }
        const report = new GC.ActiveReports.Core.PageReport();

        await report.load(reportData.reportUrl);

        if (Object.keys(reportData.params).length) {
          const attributes = Object.keys(reportData.params);
          for (const att of attributes) {
            const val = [reportData.params[att]];
            report.parameters[att].values = val;
          }
        }

        const pageDocument = await report.run();

        let result;

        if (reportData.attachmentType === "HTML") {
          result = await GC.ActiveReports.HtmlExport.exportDocument(pageDocument, reportData.settings, onProgressCallback);
        } else if (reportData.attachmentType === "XLSX") {
          result = await GC.ActiveReports.XlsxExport.exportDocument(pageDocument, reportData.settings, onProgressCallback);
        } else if (reportData.attachmentType === "PDF") {
          result = await GC.ActiveReports.PdfExport.exportDocument(pageDocument, reportData.settings, onProgressCallback);
        } else if (reportData.attachmentType === "CSV") {
          result = await GC.ActiveReports.TabularDataExport.exportDocument(pageDocument, reportData.settings, onProgressCallback);
        }

        const reader = new FileReader();

        if (reportData.attachmentType === "HTML" || reportData.attachmentType === "CSV") {
          return result.data;
        } else {
          reader.readAsBinaryString(result.data);
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.onerror = () => reject("Error occurred while reading binary string");
        });
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors
        throw error; // Rethrow the error if necessary
      }
    },
      {
        reportData: {
          reportUrl: fileName, params:
            { ...data.parameters },
          settings,
          attachmentType
        }
      }
    );

    //console.log("reportString", reportString)

    var fileData;
    if (attachmentType === "HTML" || attachmentType === "CSV") {
      var fileData = Buffer.from(reportString, "binary");
    } else {
      var fileData = reportString;
    }
    let reportName = `${data.reportName}.${extentionType}`
    await browser.close();
    return ({ "reportName": reportName, "fileBuffer": fileData, rdlxFile: fileName, "message": "Report Generated" });
    // return ({ "reportName": reportName, "fileBuffer": fileData, "message": "Report Generated" });
  }
  catch (e) {
    logger.error(e, '\n Error : Invalid raw json. ');
    return ({ error: "Invalid raw json" })
  }
};

parentPort.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.type === 'request') {
    let payload = message.data;
    payload.reportName = `${payload.templateName}`;
    (async () => {
      global.APP_USER = payload.appUser;
      let fileData = await reportGenerate(payload);
      let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, `../../resources/${fileData.rdlxFile}`)
      if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
      }
      let data = {}
      if (fileData.reportName === undefined) {
        logger.error('\n Error : Invalid raw json. ');
        data = {
          "message": 'Invalid raw json',
          "status": 401,
          "type": "Error"
        };
        postMessageToMaster({ status: 401, data: { ...data } })
      } else {
        fileData.fileBuffer = Buffer.from(fileData.fileBuffer, "binary")
        let reportdata = {
          name: `${fileData.reportName}`,
          objName: 'report',
          reportPath: fileData.reportPath || ''
        }
        await minioService.uploadReport(reportdata, fileData.fileBuffer, "buffer")
        logger.info("Report Generated & Uploaded", fileData.reportName);

        postMessageToMaster({ status: 200, data: { ...reportdata } })
      }
    })();
  }
});


module.exports = {
  reportGenerate: reportGenerate
}

I am expecting smooth generation of reports without any timeout issue and i am fine even if you suggest library other than the puppeteer.
